# What is the functionality of %||% and what does it do?

Tags: r, rlang

This has been hard to search for as everything that comes up relates to %in%. What exactly does %||% do in R? Are there any related documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: you can show the help in the R console with `help("%||%")`

Comment: It always helps to figure out which package an opertor comes from. `help("%||%")` will show that.